# What is the motivation for the defining smooth locally decodable codes?

Tags: error-correcting-codes

I am interested to understand why ***smooth locally decodable*** codes were defined historically as they were (I believe it may be because they make for easier analysis in obtaining lower bounds on locally decodable codes but would like to understand exactly how). What is their advantage over locally decodable codes that do not carry a guarantee of smoothness?

N.B. My question concerns relation between locally decodable codes and **smooth** locally decodable codes in general - the latter is not to be completely conflated with *perfectly smooth* codes.